# SQL all subquery different for max

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
mysql> select id,name from Employee where salary >= all (select salary from Employee);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,name from Employee where salary >= all (select max(salary) from Employee);

+--------+------------+
| id     | name       |
+--------+------------+
| 001    | John       |
+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the first query return 0 results? It should be the same as the 2nd query.
The salary column is decimal(12,2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same.  The first has `NULL` in a large set of comparison values.  Something cannot be bigger (or smaller or equal to) `NULL`.  So, the comparison returns `NULL` . . . and the `ALL` is not satisfied.

The second returns the `MAX()` value, because `MAX()` ignores `NULL`s.

EDIT:

Using a filter in the subquery does not make them the same, as this [rextester](http://rextester.com/XOLHLD28812) illustrates.

If *all* salary values are `NULL`, then:

```
where salary >= all (select salary from e where salary is not null);
```

returns all values.  There are no comparisons so `all` is true.

On the other hand:

```
where salary >= all (select max(salary) from e);  -- all is irrelevant
```

Returns no rows, because `NULL` comparisons are not true.

Comment: `>= all (select salary from Employee where salary is not null)`  @Gordon, would the result from the comparison to all non null values be equivalent?

Comment: where salary >= all (select max(salary) from e);  
Returns no rows?

Comment: @Sunnyday . . . It returns no rows if all the salary values are `NULL`.